# Toggle class name on parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 menus and each have different Divs.
How to add/remove class, when click #box1 on the class name "wrap" ?

ex)
click menu1 text - > div class="wrap menu1",

click menu2 text - > div class="wrap menu2"

and they shoul be toggleClass.
please help~

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/5zzzhmj8/1/

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class = "menu m1"><a href="#box1"> menu 1</a></div> 
    <div class = "menu m2"><a href="#box2"> menu 2</a></div>
    <div class = "menu m3"><a href="#box3"> menu 3</a></div>
</div>

<div class ="content" id="box1">
box 1 content
</div>

<div class ="content" id="box2">
box 2 content
</div>

<div class ="content" id="box3">
box 3 content
</div>


$("a").click(function(){
    var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
    $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");  
    $(".content:visible").not(myelement).hide();

});


.wrap { overflow:hidden;} 
.menu {float:left; width:33.3%;font-size:2em; curser:pointer;}
.content{display: none; border:1px solid #000}
.on {color:#red}

.wrap.menu1 { background:red;}
.wrap.menu2 { background:blue;}
.wrap.menu3 { background:green;}
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$("a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).text())
    var myelement = $(this).attr("href");
    $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");  
    $(".content:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    $('.wrap').removeClass('menu1 menu2 menu3').addClass($(this).text());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5zzzhmj8/4/)

Comment: thank you for answer. And how to remove class when click the same menu again ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the index of the anchors parent element

```js
$("a").click(function() {
  var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
  $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
  $(".content:visible").not(myelement).hide();
  $('.wrap').removeClass('menu1 menu2 menu3').addClass('menu' + ($(this).parent().index() + 1));
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.menu {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  font-size: 2em;
  curser: pointer;
}
.content {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000
}
.on {
  color: #red
}
.wrap.menu1 {
  background: red;
}
.wrap.menu2 {
  background: blue;
}
.wrap.menu3 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="menu m1"><a href="#box1"> menu 1</a></div>
    <div class="menu m2"><a href="#box2"> menu 2</a></div>
    <div class="menu m3"><a href="#box3"> menu 3</a></div>
</div>
<div class="content" id="box1">box 1 content</div>
<div class="content" id="box2">box 2 content</div>
<div class="content" id="box3">box 3 content</div>
```

Comment: I dont know whether my method correct or not.. which one is the good way?..  I am just a beginner... Just curios... $('.wrap').removeClass('menu1 menu2 menu3').addClass($(this).text()); ... http://jsfiddle.net/5zzzhmj8/4/

Comment: @RinoRaj you can... but there is a space `menu 1`, you can remove it

Comment: @RinoRaj you can do that - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0oy84zj7/2/ - but a better solution will be is to use a `data-*` attribute like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0oy84zj7/3/

Comment: Oh great... I will keep that in mind... Data-* attribute

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of the parent element clicked by using `$(this).parent().index()`.

Then remove the classes and add a class based on element clicked.

Below is the modified code snippet.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
    $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");  
    $(".content:visible").not(myelement).hide();
    var parent_idx = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    $(".wrap").removeClass("menu1 menu2 menu3").addClass("menu" + parent_idx);
});
```